# Поиск содержимого HTML тегов в Java

Tags: java, html, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть HTML документ:

```
<span xml:lang="en" lang="en"><b><span>Test Test
</span></b></span><span>Test</span><span>Test</span>
```

Нужно вывести на экран содержимое `<span></span>` тегов чтобы результат был таким:

```
<span xml:lang="en" lang="en"><b><span>Test Test </span></b></span>
<span>Test</span>
<span>Test</span>
```

Я так понимаю лучше всего решать такую задачу через регулярные выражения, но я только с ними познакомился и самостоятельно у меня не получилось написать выражение под данную задачу.
Полное условие задачи :

> Первым параметром в метод main приходит тег. Например, "span"
>   Вывести на консоль все теги, которые соответствуют заданному тегу
>   Каждый тег на новой строке, порядок должен соответствовать порядку следования в файле
>   Количество пробелов, \n, \r не влияют на результат
>   Файл не содержит тег CDATA, для всех открывающих тегов имеется отдельный закрывающий тег, одиночных тегов нету
>   Тег может содержать вложенные теги

Comment: Лучше всего такую задачу решать через библиотеки парсинга HTML. http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Если вы имеете дело со сколько-либо объёмным HTML или XML, лучше использовать соответствующий парсер. Регулярные выражения в данном случае - достаточно костыльный подход. Для HTML-парсинга есть библиотека _JSOUP_, например.

Comment: Согласен с Vartlok, но зависит от задачи. Вам нужна только регулярка, или вся программа?

Comment: Добавил полное описание условия задачи.

Comment: Я всё еще за парсер. Regexp должен будет учитывать всякие пробелы-переносы строк и т.д. и он будет слабо читаемым, а уж вносить изменения в него будут просто невозможно, тем более если плохо знаешь их. Не зря же "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems"

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за наводку! Тогда буду изучать парсеры.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лучше всего такую задачу решать через библиотеки парсинга HTML. Например [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org).

Regexp должен будет учитывать всякие пробелы-переносы строк и т.д. и он будет слабо читаемым, а уж вносить изменения в него будут просто невозможно, тем более если плохо знаешь их.

> [I know, I'll use regular expressions. Now they have two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

[Похожий ответ на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677045/1646082).

[Еще один ответ с английского SO, почему парсить HTML RegEpx плохая идея](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1646082).