# Нужно спарсить 1 слово с сайта.Java

Tags: java, html, строки, text

Доброго времени суток есть вот такой код, который позволяет мне спарсить всю страницу и выводит там(я не очень в джаве)  при компиляции весь хтмл страницы.

```
  Tcnm  String address = "http://bcs-express.ru/kotirovki-i-grafiki/gazp";
    URL url = new URL(address);
    BufferedReader bro = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while((s = bro.readLine())!=null){
       System.out.println(s);
    }
    bro.close();
}
}
```

А мне нужно  спарсить только текущий курс акции. который заключен в этом теге.

вот тут и цифирки

Как это сделать? подскажите в каком направлении копать)

Тег больше не повторяется, он один в коде, зачем загромождать все парсерами? jsoup? не ужели нет вариантов?

Comment: В направлении регулярных выражений.

Comment: НЕТ!!! Не надо использовать регулярные выражения при работе с HTML! используйте парсер, например: http://jsoup.org/ Я могу просто скопипастить свой ответ отсюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469596/177499 , но думаю стоит закрыть этот вопрос как дубликат.

Comment: А еще лучше поискать у сайта(сервиса) API, через который можно получить всё, что вам надо, возможно он есть. И надо работать с ним, а не парсить HTML.

Comment: на счет Апи думал.Сегодня поищу еще.